# Скачать файл по прямой ссылке

Tags: java, android, filestream

В android приложении по нажатию на кнопку должна начаться загрузка файла по прямой ссылке на загрузку файла( при открытии сразу предлагает сохранить файл). Проблема такая, нашёл в интернете множество вариантов загрузки файла(пример ниже), по нажатию, пишет либо (Read-only file system) либо происходит псевдо загрузка которая ничего не сохраняет.
Игрался с `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` и `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` снова таки ни особо помогает. Нужно что бы произошла типичная загрузка и в верхнем левом углу появилась стрелка загрузки как это обычно бывает при загрузке.

```
 public void DownloadFromUrl(String imageURL, String fileName) {  //this is the downloader method
    try {

        URL url = new URL(imageURL); //you can write here any link
        File file = new File(ctx.getFilesDir().getPath().toString(),fileName);

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.d("ImageManager", "download begining");
        Log.d("ImageManager", "download url:" + url);
        Log.d("ImageManager", "downloaded file name:" + fileName);
                    /* Open a connection to that URL. */
        URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

                    /*
                     * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
                     */

            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();


                    /*
                     * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
                     */
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            //We create an array of bytes
            byte[] data = new byte[50];
            int current = 0;

            while ((current = bis.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                buffer.write(data, 0, current);
            }

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(buffer.toByteArray());
            fos.close();
            Log.d("ImageManager", "download ready in"
                    + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000)
                    + " sec");


    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("ImageManager", "Error: " + e);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, Ваш код работает, по крайней мере скопировав и запустив, я смог скачать, к примеру, эту HTML-страницу (обратите внимание, что она сохраняется в интернал сторадже).

Другое дело, что Вы, как я понимаю, хотите скачать файл через менеджер загрузки с нотификацией статус баре. Для этого необходимо использовать класс [DownloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html), пример использования можно найти [вот здесь](http://blog.vogella.com/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/). И не забудьте про пермишн для доступа в интернет.

Comment: проблема уже решена. именно так как вы написали.